# Trigger help referencing three objects used as validation rule

Tags: apex, validation-rule, before-trigger

I am in need of help with creating a trigger that acts as a validation rule.  Usually I would create a validation rule for this process however I have hit an error that states I have met my limit of 15 relationships, and at this time I cannot delete the relationships established.  Here are the details:

**Objects and Their Respective Fields:**

- Lead_Source__c (custom object the rule will be placed on)

  ```
  -Effort__c (look up field - Opportunity object)
  -External_Recruiter_Firm_Name__c (look up field - External Recruiter)
  ```
- Opportunity

  ```
  -Channel__c
  ```
- External_Recruiter__c

  ```
  -All_Active_Channels__c
  ```

What I am trying to accomplish:

Whenever a user enters a new Lead source Record and selects a name in the LeadSource.External_Recruiter_Firm_Name__c field, the LeadSource.Effort__r.Channel__c equals "PCG" then the ExternalRecruiter.All_Active_Channels__c field should "CONTAIN" PCG.  If not an error message should show "The External Recruiter selected does not have an active channel contract!"

I know this may be alot. I can figure out the declarative side of things but i still have not figured out salesforce triggers and still learning. If someone could create a framework for me or provide some help that would be greatly appreciated.

If you have additional questions please feel free to ask.

Thank you,

Chad

Comment: Hi Chad. We will gladly help you with your problems/bugs, but you should show us the exact problem, what you tried so far, what you expect and what is happening. If you really need somebody to write code for you, you should ask a colleague-developer or hire somebody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing worth noting from the get-go: In the nicest way possible, I feel obligated to tell you that such a complicated relationship structure sounds like the aftermath of a tech debt nightmare created by not having an on-staff developer architecting your use of the platform, and the expressed "cannot change" policy should really be evaluated, since you're hitting your validation rule limits and you don't know how to make triggers (even if you did, I think it would just make you more aware of the problem you're walking into, it wouldn't solve it). It sounds like you need someone to re-architect your setup before it gets worse and becomes "unstable". I could elaborate on that further, but I wouldn't feel right not pointing that out.

That being said, you're obviously trying to learn how to write triggers. I'm not an expert, but this should help you get started.

```
trigger LeadSourceTrigger on Lead_Source__c( before insert ) {
   Map<Id, Lead_Source__c> leadSourceByRecruiterId = new Map<Id, Lead_Source__c>();

   for(Lead_Source__c leadSource : Trigger.New()){
     if(leadSource.External_Recruiter_Firm_Name__c != NULL){
          leadSourceByRecruiterId.put( leadSource.External_Recruiter_Firm_Name__c, leadSource);
       }
    }

   List<External_Recruiter__c> externalRecruiters = [SELECT Id, All_Active_Channels__c FROM External_Recruiter__c WHERE Id IN: leadSourceByRecruiterId.KeySet()];
   for(External_Recruiter__c recruiter: externalRecruiters){
      if(String.ValueOf(recruiter.All_Active_Channels__c).contains('PCG') != TRUE){
         leadSourceByRecruiterId.get(recruiter.Id).addError('The External Recruiter selected does not have an active channel contract!');
      }
   }
}
```

*** When you say : "...the LeadSource.Effort__r.Channel__c equals 'PCG'... ", I wasn't sure if you meant we need to set that or check that, or were just stating that fact, so I excluded any code referencing it.

Notes (to help you on your trigger mastery voyage):

-Record Id isn't available on before insert, which is why I put the entire Lead_Source__c object in the map, but we do want to use before insert for obvious reasons (we're trying to prevent DML insert if criteria isn't met).

-You can't traverse lookup fields using Trigger.new(). That is to say, even if a relationship exists between one object and another as a result of a look up field, when you put a trigger on an object and access all the incoming records that are hitting the trigger via Trigger.new(), you cannot access the related object's field values without querying that related object separately. Which is why we query External_Recruiter__c instead of just accessing leadSource.External_Recruiter_Name__r.All_Active_Channels__c .

-This trigger is bulkified, meaning that although it sounds like you only plan on having the trigger process one record when it fires, (hence the pop-up on a single page shown to the user), the code is designed to process many records at once, in case something like dataloader causes it to run and thus, we avoid breaking it. However, there is one exception to this - Fair warning - addError() doesn't necessarily play well with bulk insertion outside the UI. Read here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008zMpIAI, but considering you need to learn to walk before you can run, I'd still suggest this for now.

Comment: thank you KB.  yes, I'm learning the ropes of writing classes and triggers.  the developer before me wrote a lot of code and we are having a lot of problems with the previously written code.  thanks for your input.  I'll take a look.